# How to setup email forwarding with own domain on Amazon EC2?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a hard time understanding how I could setup e-mail **forwarding** on Amazon EC2 for my own domain, meaning how I can forward every email sent to `...@mydomain.com` to my personal email address.

I'm using Amazon SES for sending emails. But what about incoming e-mails - is there any simpler way than setting up a complete e-mail server? As I'm using IP forwarding for my domain, I can't set up  email forwarding with my domain provider.

I know this is kind of a general question.. I'd appreciate any help that points me in the right direction!

Comment: Don't even bother with all of that, try https://www.migadu.com and don't waste money and time on "emails"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently there is no incoming email (POP, IMAP, etc) managed service from AWS, so you'd need to set up your own mail receiving and forwarding.

Using Postfix as a mail server, setup would look like this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/

If forwarding is all you need, you could set up a email service outside AWS (Google Apps?) and redirect using GMail rules, for example.

**UPDATE:** Amazon Web Services has announced WorkMail as a email and calendaring service. http://aws.amazon.com/workmail/

**UPDATE:** [Amazon SES now supports inbound mail](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/09/amazon-ses-now-supports-inbound-email/)

Comment: Amazon uses something called WorkMail now

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid However that only works with Outlook / via AD, no POP or IMAP :(

Comment: WorkMail is **4 USD / User / Month**.. Is there any free solution to forward mails?

Comment: What about Amazon SES?

Comment: As mentioned by an AWS team member [here](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx3HQEJUJNVABG8/Receiving-Email-with-Amazon-SES), there is no simple setup to use Amazon SES to forward emails (see "You are correct, SES does not currently support a mail relay action"). I've found [this](https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder), an AWS Lambda script that uses SES to forward emails, but I've yet to try it.

Answer (score 23):

Use a mail forwarding service. Eg. [improvmx.com](https://improvmx.com)

It allows you to forward emails directed at your domain to any email address of your choice.
All you have to do is add an MX record for your domain to point to improvmx.

And its free.

Comment: Whereas improvmx.com may be a great product, this is not really answering the question. The OP is specifically asking about an EC2 instance on AWS.

Comment: @bersling could you expand on what your mean? If you later decide to use a different email forwarder what would happen?

Comment: with a different one it would work, but in improvmx you can't change the forwarding once it's set. maybe this has changed in the mean time though.

Comment: [ImprovMX](https://improvmx.com) recently pushed a new version of their service. You can now change your email address and even add custom aliases for all of your domain.

Answer (score 9):

**SES + Lambda for email redirections**

This guy made up a lambda function to redirect emails received via amazon SES. There are detailed instructions on the readme

https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder

Comment: this looked good but hasn't been kept upto date. Similar solutions also at  https://github.com/serverless/serverless search for `SES` or `email`.

Comment: Well I am running this lambda ses forwarder code for one of my own domains, it's been working well so far.

Comment: could you update step 2? with a preset policy offered from amazon if possible? that's where I'm stuck

Comment: You need to configure your S3 bucket `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3-BUCKET-NAME/*"` so unless you want to use preset policy giving access to everything, I'm not sure you want a preset policy...

Answer (score 1):

There is an official post on AWS's Blog that addresses this exact need.
It's quite simple to setup, and only uses SES, Lambda, and S3, so it's fully **Serverless**, no need to have any servers running.

It's also quite cheap. There is a section in the post to give you an estimation.

Here : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/forward-incoming-email-to-an-external-destination/

Answer (score -1):

You can create a forwarder rule in WorkMail. It requires logging in as the end user to create. Step by step [here](https://feeney.mba/email-forwarding-using-native-aws-services.html). Note that forwarding in this way changes the header of the email to look like the end user sent it instead of actual source. Not ideal.

Comment: The link is dead